# Background image to small for desktop sceen size?

Tags: html, css

Hey Friends I noticed that the background image doesn't stretch the whole width of the screen when I set the screen width to 2560px, which is a standard desktop screen size I assume. I'm not sure though this is the first time I've done media queries. I also don't know how to upload images on here or Imgur so you can see it in action. So here's a pic [image: here]

https://jsfiddle.net/khcwnm90/
Also so the code posted on SO is just so I can post the fiddle link. I think its pretty stupid that I have to do this because the only reason I'm posting the fiddle link is because I have too much code to post here.

```css
body, html {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/*---HEADER---*/

li a {
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102,0.75);
}

header {
 background-image: url(../img/wall2.jpeg);
 height: 100vh;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

nav {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px grey;
}

ul {
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.55rem;
 margin-right: 20px;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
}

li a:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #1a1a1a;
 transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.after:after {
 position: relative;
 left: 12px;
 top: 2px;
 display: inline-block;
 content: "";
 width: 1px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102,0.25);
}

.logo { color: red;
 font-size: 3.7rem;
 margin: 10px;
 opacity: 1;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

.phrase {
 text-align: center;
}

.phrase p {
 color: white;
 font-size: 3.5rem;
 font-family: 'Arvo';
 margin-bottom: 30px;

}

.phrase a {
 background-color: red;
 border-radius: 25px;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Bitter';
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.phrase a:hover {
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
 background-color: #cc0000;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.phrase .fas {
 display: block;
 color: white;
 font-size: 3.5rem;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

/*---PROMISE---*/

.stats {
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px grey;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: white;
}

.stats div {
 display: inline-block;
 flex-basis: 35%;
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.stat-info {
 font-size: 2rem;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.stat-num {
 color: red;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 3rem;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: bolder;
}

.stats div:before {
 display: inline-block;
 content: '';
 width: 2px;
 height: 35px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.60);
}

.promise {
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url('../img/concrete.jpg');
 background-position: center;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
}

.promise .wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.promise h1 {
 position: relative;
 top: 40px;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Arvo';
 font-size: 3.5rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 0;
 word-spacing: 7px;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 100px grey;
}

.promise p {
 color: white;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 40px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-right: 50px;
}

/*---FOOTER---*/

.footer .wrapper {
 display: flex;
}

.footer div {
 display: inline-block;
 flex-basis: 33.33%;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.footer h1 {
 font-size: 2rem;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.footer .inner {
 margin-left: 55px;
}

.social .inner {
 margin-left: 45px;
}

.contact .inner {
 margin-left: 35px;
}

.footer .inner:before {
 display: inline-block;
 content: '';
 width: 27.1%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 54px;
}

.footer h1 span {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

.footer h1 span:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.wrap:before {
 content: '';
 width: 100px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 55px;
}

.links a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
 transition: color 0.4s ease;
}

.links a:hover {
 color: red;
}

.contact p {
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
}

.social i {
 font-size: 1.7rem;
 margin-right: 5px;
 position: relative;
 top: -20px;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.social i:hover {
 color: red;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#msg {
 margin-top: -15px;
}

.footer-textarea {
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.2);
 outline: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 resize: none;
 width: 89%;
}

.footer button {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 9.5%;
 margin-top: -17px;
 border: none;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 transition: all ease 0.4s;
 outline: none;
}

button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: red;
}

.dark {
 color: red;
}

.copyright {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
}



/*-------MEDIA QUERIES-------*/



/*---LAPTOP-LARGE---*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 16.5%;
 }

}

/*---LAPTOP---*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 .logo {
  font-size: 3rem;
 }

 nav li {
  font-size: 2rem;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header {
  height: 100vh;
 }

 .phrase p {
  font-size: 3rem;
 }

 .phrase a {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 }

 .stats p {
  font-size: 2rem;
 }
 
 /*---FOOTER---*/
 
 .footer .inner {
  margin-left: 30px;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 88%;
 }

 .footer button {
  margin-right: 10.25%;
 }

 .footer h1 span {
   display: inline;
   position: relative;
 }

 .footer h1 span:after {
   content: '';
   height: 2px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-height: 1366px) {

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header {
  height: 80vh;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 823px) {

 /*---MAIN---*/

 .phrase p {
  font-size: 3rem;
 }

}

/*------LANDSCAPE-MODE------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 812px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 nav li {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
 }

 .logo {
  font-size: 2.7rem;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header {
  height: 100vh;
 }

 .stats p {
  font-size: 2rem;
 }

 .promise p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
 }



 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 8.5%;
 }

 .contact .inner {
  margin-right: 20px;
 }

}

/*---TABLET---*/

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 nav li {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
 }

 .logo {
  font-size: 3rem;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 .phrase {
  top: 300px;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer h1 span {
   display: inline;
   position: relative;
 }

 .footer h1 span:after {
   content: '';
   height: 2px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
 }

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 7.4%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 731px) {

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 6%;
 }

 .contact .inner p {
  margin: 5px;
 }

}

/*------LANDSCAPE-MODE-MOBILE------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 715px) {
 
 /*---NAV---*/

 .phrase {
  margin-top: 30px;
 }

 .phrase p {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
 }

 .phrase a {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 }

 nav ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }

 nav li {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
 }

 nav .logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .links a {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  top: -13px;
 }

 .contact .inner {
  margin-right: 15px;
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  width: 90.5%;
 }

 .footer button {
  margin-top: -18px;
  margin-right: 7%;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 586px) {

 /*---MAIN---*/

 .phrase p {
  font-size: 2.7rem;
 }

 .stats p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .footer div {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .footer .inner {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer .inner:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 100vw;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 48px;
 }

 .footer h1 span:after {
   content: '';
   height: 2px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 1px;
   left: 0;
 }

 .social .inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
 }

 .links a {
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .social h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 #msg {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 25.5%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 80px;
 }

 .footer button {
  right: 9.25%;
  margin-top: 0.2px;
 }

 .social i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 88.5%;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .copyright {
  background-color: red;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .copyright span {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {

 /*---MAIN---*/

 .phrase p {
  font-size: 2rem;
 }

 .phrase a {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
 }

 .stats p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 }

 .promise p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .footer div {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .footer .inner {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer .inner:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 48px;
 }

 .footer h1 span:after {
   content: '';
   height: 2px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 1px;
   left: 0;
 }

 .social .inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
 }

 .social .inner:before {
  width: 100vw;
 }

 .links a {
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .social h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 #msg {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 25.5%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 80px;
 }

 .footer button {
  right: 9.25%;
  margin-top: 0.2px;
 }

 .social i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 88.5%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .copyright {
  background-color: red;
 }

 .copyright span {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 517px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 nav li {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .footer div {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .footer .inner {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer .inner:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 100vw;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 48px;
 }

 .social .inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
 }

 .footer h1 span:after {
     content: '';
     height: 2px;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 1px;
  left: 0;
 }

 .links a {
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .social h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 #msg {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25.5%;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
 }

 .footer button {
  right: 9.25%;
  margin-top: 0.2px;
 }

 .social i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-right: 7px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 88.5%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .copyright {
  background-color: red;
 }

 .copyright span {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
 }

}

/*---MOBILE---*/

@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 .logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin-left: 10px;
 }

 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

 nav li {
  display: none;
 }

 .ham-menu {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .m1, .m2, .m3 {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 .phrase {
  top: 179px;
 }

 .phrase p {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .phrase a {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  padding: 7px;
 }

 .phrase .fas {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
 }

 .stats p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
 }

 .stats div {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .stats div:before {
  height: 20px;
 }

 .promise h1 {
  font-size: 2.7rem;
 }

 .promise p {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .footer div {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .footer .inner {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer .inner:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 100vw;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 48px;
 }

 .social .inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -9.5px;
 }

 .footer h1 span {
   display: inline;
   position: relative;
 }

 .footer h1 span:after {
   content: '';
   height: 2px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 1px;
   left: 0;
 }

 .links a {
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .social h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 #msg {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 25.5%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 80px;
 }

 .footer button {
  right: 9.25%;
  margin-top: 0.2px;
 }

 .social i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 88.5%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .copyright {
  background-color: red;
 }

 .copyright span {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
 .footer button {
  margin-right: 8.5%;
 }
}

/*---HAM-MENU-ANIMATIONS---*/

@keyframes m1 {
 from {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
 }
 to {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  top: 12px;
 }
}

@keyframes m2 {
 from {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
 }
 to {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

@keyframes m3 {
 from {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
 }
 to {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: relative;
  top: -10.5px;
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! That's quite a lot of code, and as such, it's a little hard to find the cause of your problem. In order for us to help you better, could you please divide and conquer to isolate your problem, and then update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New rule for `.header`, remove `background-attachment: fixed;` and add `background-size: cover;`:

```
header {
  background-image: url(../img/wall2.jpeg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the picture in the header and it seems like you only edited the height and not  the width.  Im not sure about the specs of the picture which might come out stretched but try putting this...

width: 100%;

in the style section you put the picture in . . . (header {})

if you are going to have that image as just the header then you should probably limit it to only a portion of the height but the full width.  Its a lot easier to use percentages as much as you can because of the transition from mobile to desktop.  When a user looks at a web page from their phone and its in pixels then it would be a lot large than they would probably like.

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size: cover`, it will stretch an image to fill the full size of your element.

Answer (score 0):

`<body style="background-image:url(bgimage.jpg)">` use this  code 
 and then check.